# How to send and receive binary data using C# Windows Phone 7 WebClient?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, protobuf-net

Speaking as concisely as possible: What is involved in sending and receiving binary data via the WebClient class in Windows Phone 7, using HTTP POST? Is WebClient the correct class to use?

Currently, I am trying to call OpenReadAsync() inside an OpenWriteCompleted event handler after writing the request binary data. The request data is being written on an asynchronous result to OpenWriteAsync(). I am doing this for the purpose of sending and receiving Protocol Buffer data encoded using ProtoBuf-Net, to a http URI.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks,

Nick

Comment: Is it specifically http you want to use? And: does it work?

Comment: Hey Marc, I edited the question. I am certainly trying to send HTTP POST requests with binary data.

Comment: And : does it work? What happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to implement POST (FILES) yourself.

But check out this:

http://mytoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Http

(simple POST, GZIP, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

WebClient appears to be the wrong class to use. I am now using HttpWebRequest with great results.